# How do I add an SVG file to a React project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to add some SVG images to my project. I have the downloaded images and have tried dropping them into my file system in [MP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) format and [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format, but this is not working. I'm wondering how I can add these downloaded files into my project.

I've tried everything I've found on Google, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Please outline what you've tried. Its just a case of `import`ing them and using the URL on the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag. You could also use https://react-svgr.com/ to convert the SVG to a react component.

Comment: Re *"this is not working"*: Can you be more specific? What happened? What were the symptoms?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
import { ReactComponent as MySvgFile } from './mySvgFile.svg';
```

And then render it like this:

```html
<div>
  <MySvgFile />
</div>
```

Comment: This assumes you have the SVG file in the same folder as your react component

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, yes that's what I want to do. The only problem is I don't know how to get the svg file into the same folder that I want to render it. I have one as a download on my pc but I'm not sure where to move it from there